# Smooth Scrolling not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been bashing my head against the wall trying plenty of smooth scrolling plugins to work why the signup button won't smooth scroll down to the #target section properly.

Please help hive mind, I am using CSS tricks code.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

You can see the pen with all the html css and other js at

https://codepen.io/samducker/pen/RVoORy

Answer (score 1):

Cancel your code and try out this one (It's maybe a bit fast change it maybe to 500), it might be a bit laggy if you have so much content between your button and the anchor:

```
/*Scroll Down Button*/
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works a treat brother, how come the previous code I was using works on all of the css tricks examples but didn't work on my page?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a copy paste issue. Because you can stay with your solution and just change ('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])') to  ('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])')

Comment: I don't wanna be greedy but can you select the answer as correct with the green tick. Would be helpfull ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector seems to be incorrect. Therefor the click function will not fire when you click on the button and will fallback to it's default anchor behavior. I forked your codepen and changed the jQuery selector to `a` see: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbmNXd

Try to change the jQuery selector to what works for your application.